# Exemplo de importação de XML usando Lavarel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Alguem tem um exemplo claro para importar XML usando Laravel Parser ou SimpleXML ...? Eu tenho um cenário onde eu tenho que importar um XML de um sistema externo que contém várias informações geradas em um XML ... Eu preciso para obter este XML gerado e exibir esses dados no site ... Obrigado! 
Toda ajuda é bem-vinda

Comment: Tem o endereço, tem o layout das informações, já fez alguma programação?

Comment: Estou tentando pegar o XML exato, para mostrar melhor o que quero fazer... obrigado por responder @Laerte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter xml através de um URL:

```
//se o caminho esteja hospedado noutro servidor
$url = "https://www.........";

//caso o caminho esteja hospedado no próprio servidor
//coloque o ficheiro no caminho: 'public/assets/xml/file.xml'
$url = asset('assets/xml/file.xml');

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

dd($xml);
```

Para aceder a um child:

```
if(isset($xml->child)) {
    dd($xml->child);
}
```

Comment: Desculpas pela demora nessa resposta. Obrigado por responder. Eu tenho a url onde o sistema hospeda os arquivos porem nao sei como ler eles. eu ja tenho todos arquivos do xml gerado pelo sistema. Veja a url: http://dianopolis.megasofttransparencia.com.br/dianopolis-transparencia/transparencia/index.xhtml

Comment: Como assim? Onde tem o xml?

Comment: Eu tenho um arquivo XML com informações, queria ler todas essas informações...

Comment: Editei de forma a responder a essa questão.